# How to `include` two separate references of same model using Sequelize ORM?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm building a website using the MEAN stack but replacing MongoDB with PostGRES and, as a result, using Sequelize ORM.

I have two models -- `User` and `AudioConfig`. A `User` can have many `AudioConfig` and an `AudioConfig` belongs to a `User` by the `createdBy` and `updatedBy`.

Here's how my association looks like using Sequelize

```
models.User.hasMany(models.AudioConfig, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'createdBy',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
models.User.hasMany(models.AudioConfig, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'updatedBy'
  }
});
models.AudioConfig.belongsTo(models.User, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'createdBy',
    as: 'createdBy',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
models.AudioConfig.belongsTo(models.User, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'updatedBy',
    as: 'updatedBy'
  }
});
```

In my `findAll` query for `AudioConfig`, I have tried several variations from what I've found online but none appear to work as I expect:

```
var Db = require('../../models');
var entityModel = Db.AudioConfig;

exports.index = function (req, res) {
  entityModel.findAll({
      include: {all:true}
    })
    .then(function (entities) {
      return res.status(200).json(entities);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    })
};

// And I've tried this...
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  entityModel.findAll({
      include: [
        {model: Db.User, as: 'createdBy'},
        {model: Db.User, as: 'updatedBy'}
      ]
    })
    .then(function (entities) {
      return res.status(200).json(entities);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    })
};

// And this too...
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  entityModel.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Db.User
        }
      ]
    })
    .then(function (entities) {
      return res.status(200).json(entities);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    })
};
```

Now, in my database, I have a single record of `AudioConfig` that has two different `User` references -- one for `createdBy` and another for `updatedBy`. But when I do a query for `AudioConfig`, I only get the `User` record back for the `updatedBy` field.

```
[
  {
    "id": "e3011e31-b907-47ad-99f3-61016283a523",
    "sampleRate": 16000,
    "format": "WAV",
    "channel": 2,
    "bitRate": 16,
    "createdAt": "2016-05-01T16:30:11.847Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-05-01T16:30:11.847Z",
    "createdBy": "1375263f-a3f0-4eef-800f-99b28fdce9d8",
    "updatedBy": "5bb8cac0-b916-4000-81fe-9b1f8f597847",
    "User": {
      "id": "5bb8cac0-b916-4000-81fe-9b1f8f597847",
      "email": "johnd@email.com",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "resetPasswordToken": null,
      "resetPasswordTokenExpiresOn": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-05-01T16:30:11.816Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-05-01T16:30:11.816Z",
      "roleId": "10ae3879-9f9f-4370-aa47-3677c492afd8"
    }
  }
]
```

How do I get it so that `createdBy` value of UUID is replaced with the `User` object associated with it? And same for the `updatedBy` field?

I'm somewhat expecting the same behavior as with [MongoDB and Mongoose's `populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Have you tried defining the 'as' property in the foreign key object on both ends of the relationship? I see you only have it on the belongsTo but not hasMany. In their documentation it is set on both ends.

Comment: @GrimurD, I tried what you suggested but I got the same result back.

Comment: Try changing the names in the 'as' so the names dont conflict with the fields on the models. For example createdByUser and updatedByUser

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally realized what the problem is, you have the as property set on the foreign key object. This should hopefully solve it, unfortunately I can't test it myself at the moment.

```js
models.User.hasMany(models.AudioConfig, {
  as: 'createdByUser',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'createdBy',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
models.User.hasMany(models.AudioConfig, {
  as: 'updatedByUser',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'updatedBy'
  }
});
models.AudioConfig.belongsTo(models.User, {
  as: 'createdByUser',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'createdBy',
    allowNull: false
  }
});
models.AudioConfig.belongsTo(models.User, {
  as: 'updatedByUser'
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'updatedBy'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution, along with using `include: {all:true}` in my `findAll` query, did the trick.

Comment: instead of using `include: {all:true}` in `findAll` you can use `include: {model: models.User, as: 'createdByUser'}`, etc. Be sure to use `as:` in all associations to the same model in your Sequelize model declaration.

Comment: Isn't this still strange though that you can't decide which associated models to include, it is either one or all?